# Can Java package code identify the application that imported it?

Tags: java

I have a Java package of common code that multiple different web applications import and use.

Can the running package code identify which application it's in? (something Tomcat-specific would still be useful)

Is there a generic way for imported Java code to identify the class that imported it?

Thank you!

Comment: What do you want to achieve with the knowledge about the running application? This is in most cases a bad practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no simple way to do this.

But I see two options:

- You can try to load some class that you know application have.
- You can analize stack trace to check that some method in stack belong to application in question.